# xe5 debugger steps into a wrong line

Tags: debugging, hyperlink, compilation, c++builder-xe5

The debugger doesn't allow me to set break points for many of lines of one of the library file. And when I step into the function call which causes the error and do a step by step walk through, it turns out the program is running into some wired lines in the library, such as

empty line or };

instead of the correct method.

I have do a clean, rebuild and make, but it still behaves similarly.

Any idea about what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out although the library has been rebuild, the linker is actually linking the code to another library within a different folder.

Simply just go to the project options, c++ (shared options) library path and check weather the path to the lib file is something you are expecting. If not, delete the old path and change it to the correct one and you will have your problem solved.